# Can we abort a transaction in blockchain?

Tags: database, transactions, cryptography, blockchain, public-key-encryption

Due to security advantages through chaining of blocks and public key encryption, Is it possible to implement a transaction abort in blockchains?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't abort or revert a blockchain transaction when it's complete. When the transaction is mined, it's stored in the immutable block, meaning it'll never be changed.